# how to create single dictionary from pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
     name  value
0  user_x     34
1  user_y     23
```

I need to create a single dictionary from the above dataframe as follows:

```
dict = {"user_x": 34, "user_y": 23}
```

I tried the code below.
Let's say I have a DataFrame f:

```
f.to_dict(orient='dict')  with output as:
{'value': {0: 34, 1: 23}, 'name': {0: 'user_x', 1: 'user_y'}}

f.to_dict(orient='dict')  with output as:
{'value': {0: 34, 1: 23}, 'name': {0: 'user_x', 1: 'user_y'}}

dict = {"user_x": 34, "user_y": 23, ....}
```

Comment: df.set_index('name').value.to_dict()

Comment: Thank you! It worked :-)

Comment: just `df.to_dict()` should work

Answer (score 0):

Given the following data:

```
data = {'name' :["user_x", 'user_y'], 'value': [34,23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You can use a dictionary comprehension to get the exact output you want.

```
output_dict = {x:y for x,y in df.values}
print(output_dict)

{'user_y': 23, 'user_x': 34}
```